# wkhtmltopdf renders blank page when Vue is used

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vuejs3, wkhtmltopdf

When I make a new Vue project and use wkhtmltopdf, it renders a blank PDF page.

Steps to reproduce:

1. `vue create hello-world`
2. Choose: Default (Vue 3, babel, eslint)
3. `npm run serve`
4. Check in browser that it works: http://localhost:8081
5. `./wkhtmltopdf --javascript-delay 10000 --debug-javascript "http://localhost:8081/" "test.pdf"`

The response is:

```
Loading pages (1/6)
Warning: undefined:0 TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function
Counting pages (2/6)
Resolving links (4/6)
Loading headers and footers (5/6)
Printing pages (6/6)
Done
```

The PDF is rendered, but the page is blank. I might say that a JavaScript delay of 10 seconds is more than enough to render it after load.

This is just a case to illustrate my problem. My real project is more complex, because I use webpack, axios and more. While I get one warning in the example above, I get multiple warnings during processing of wkhtmltopdf in my real project:

```
Loading pages (1/6)
Warning: http://localhost:8080/build/runtime.js:1 SyntaxError: Parse error
Warning: http://localhost:8080/build/vendors-node_modules_core-js_internals_set-species_js-node_modules_core-js_modules_es_array_f-0880e9.js:7 SyntaxError: Parse error
Warning: http://localhost:8080/build/vendors-node_modules_axios_index_js-node_modules_core-js_modules_es_array_reverse_js-node_mod-330420.js:7 SyntaxError: Parse error
Warning: http://localhost:8080/build/src_Resources_js_templateLoader_js.js:8 SyntaxError: Parse error
Warning: http://localhost:8080/build/app_pdf.js:8 SyntaxError: Parse error
Counting pages (2/6)
Resolving links (4/6)
Loading headers and footers (5/6)
Printing pages (6/6)
Done
```

The result is a blank PDF page too. In my real project, the URL works fine in the browser, just like the hello-world project above.

But anyway, let's focus on this Hello World example. What should I do different to make wkhtmltopdf work with Vue? Thanks for any help.

EDIT: The crash happens before it even reaches the app's script. Therefor it seems irrelevant to share my app code here. Using the --window-status option of wkhtmltopdf will also not work because of this.